# Where do I start to make an Android 2D game?

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I am still very new to coding and Stack Overflow, this is my first question. I have been coding random apps, and experimenting with Android for the last 3-4 months. I recently published my first app. Just a day counter, with a widget. Still pretty basic, but my intention has always been to create Android games. My question is where do I start to make an Android game? Should I make games using just the default libraries and API on Android Studio or should I just make a Java game on Eclipse then try to import it to Android. I am trying to start by doing a simple 2D game. Can someone please explain to me what options do I have, or point me in the right direction please. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to code using OpenGL ES?

Comment: Use Android Studio, not Eclipse. AS is seamless, updates are straightforward, the debugger is fine. To be honest, I tried Eclipse at first and was very frustrated by it, so there's some emotion attached; however, while it's debatable, I think most who've tried both (or only tried AS) would agree.

Comment: My Suggestion : use Unity or Libgdx

Comment: No, I don't know how to code using OpenGL ES? Is there a bright future there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either Android standard API like Canvas API or OpenGL ES A good book explaining both aspects is [Mario Zechner's Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428). You can find a good examples of using both API in different games.

Also you can use third party frameworks and engines. Good one is [Cocos2d-x](http://cocos2d-x.org/) (it is c++ framework) it is well known open source cross platform game development framework with good community and a lot of examples and books over the internet.

Also you can check [Unity](http://www.unity3d.com/) (C# or JavaScript) it is proprietary game engine extremely easy to learn and use (you can make many features like sprite animation without any code). This engine have large community and books. There is also a ton of well written documentation. (There are two licenses personal and pro).

Another good is [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) (C++) it is similar to Unity but from other developer. This is also good engine for game development and free to download and use (you must pay 5% royalty to epic games only if you earned more than 3k on your game).

There is also [libGdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html) framework for cross platform development (java).

You can also check [marmalade](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/)(C++), [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) (Lua), [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) (pure android game engine).

My own opinion you should check Unity or Cocos2d-x. These are two most popular engines for Android/iOS game development so you will easily find books, videos and tutorials and even video courses ([1](https://www.coursera.org/learn/game-development) [2](https://www.coursera.org/learn/gamedev-platforms)) how to work with these engines.

Answer (score 0):

you should try andengine for 2d games. you can find basic tutorials  [here](http://www.matim-dev.com/tutorials.html)

Answer (score 0):

Start with GameSalad
easy and fast.